# How to pass field value to referenced node template?

Tags: 8, theming

I have content type A. It has field reference to content type B.

I'm rendering referenced node B from content type A twig template like:

```
{{ content.field_referenced_object }}
```

And that works well.

I also render some type A filed inside it's template like:

```
{{ content.field_some }}
```

which also works.

Problem is that I need that `field_some` value to be displayed from referenced object B template instead of object A template, to optimize page markup. How can I pass value from content type A twig template to content type B twig template?

It twig it can be done when including template like:

```
{% include 'template.html' with {'foo': 'bar'} %}
```

But is there some analogy for Drupal 8 theming?

Comment: TL,DR: No. Long version: Conceptionally entity render arrays are self-contained, cachable units. The Drupal way would be either preprocessing and a custom cache context based on the referencing node, or a views block with a contextual filter. But IMHO both ways are terrible workarounds, your Twig snippet is the better technique.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TL,DR: No.

Long version:

Conceptionally entity render arrays are self-contained, cachable units. The Drupal way would be either preprocessing and a custom cache context based on the referencing node, or a views block with a contextual filter.

But IMHO both ways are terrible workarounds, your Twig snippet `{% include ... with ... %}` is the better technique.